# Owl carousel 2 does not display the correct items with different class name

Tags: items, classname, owl-carousel-2

I saw that this question was already asked but the solutions just didn't work for me. I have this items in my system :

```
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>

<div class="blog-carousel owl-carousel">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

script side :

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 2,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive: {
        0: { items: 1 },
        685: { items: 2 },
    }
});

$('.blog-carousel:not(".owl-carousel")').owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive: {
        0: { items: 1 },
        685: { items: 2 }
    }
});
```

At first, on the second div group, I only put `blog-carousel` as a class name and simply call `$('.blog-carousel').owlCarousel({})` but it cannot be displayed in carousel. Then I saw others mentioned that the class name 'owl-carousel' is a mandatory. And that is how my code turned to this.

So the issue is, the default owl-carousel, I wanted to show only 2 items and show 3 items for the blog group. But my blog items still display 2 instead of 3. It seems like, it's reading everything from the first script.

Answer (score 0):

In second slider you mentioned `items: 2` for screen width greater than 685px. So only two items are showing. Add some other breakpoint and make `items: 3`. In this snippet, I added breakpoint as 768px.

```
$('.blog-carousel').owlCarousel({
  responsiveClass:true,
  responsive: {
    // breakpoint from 0 up
    0: { items: 1 },
    // breakpoint from 685 up
    685: { items: 2 },
    // breakpoint from 768 up
    768: { items: 3 }
  }
});
```